# как унаследоваться от абстрактного объекта?

Tags: javascript, ооп

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

у меня есть абстрактный объект для единиц техники Unit(). он содержит свойства, общие для более конкретных видов техники(для танков, лодок, вертолётов и т.д)

```
var Unit = function(data) { 
    console.dir('in unit-constructor: ' + data);
  this.x_coord = data.x_coord;
  this.y_coord = data.y_coord;
  this.color = data.color;
};

Unit.prototype = {
  create: function() { 
    console.log('create Unit');
  }  
}
```

проблема в том, что конкретная единица техники не может унаследоваться от него:

```
var playerUnit = function(data) { 
    console.dir('in playerUnit-constructor: ' + data.y_coord);
  Unit.apply(this, data);

  console.log('pre create playerUnit');

  this.create();
};

//playerUnit.prototype = Object.create(Unit.prototype);
//playerUnit.prototype = new Unit();



var App = function(options) { 
  this.player = new playerUnit({
    gameObj: this,
    x_coord: 1,
    y_coord: 1,
    color: 'red'
  });  
};


new App();
```

выражается это в том, что в консоли выводится следующее:

> in playerUnit-constructor: 1
>
> in unit-constructor: undefined
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x_coord' of undefined

https://jsfiddle.net/kfp34uug/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете *не тот* метод.

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) ожидает **массив** аргументов, а не список. Как правило, `apply` используется вместе с объектом [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) в случае *переменного* (неизвестного) числа аргументов.

В вашем же случае, когда вы делаете:

`Unit.apply(this, data);`

`data` воспринимается как *цельный массив параметров*, и в конструктор `Unit` в качестве 1-го параметра передается `data[0]`, а не `data` (как вы судя по всему ожидаете).

Поэтому в вашем случае вместо `apply` нужно использ-ть [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
Unit.call(this, data);
```